# Contract in Roman Law

Tags: contract-law, legal-history, research, from-the-latin

I would like to find out more about contract in Roman law. Any information about contract responsibility and guilt would be helpful. I am unable to find any real life examples of those contracts, are there any of them? I tried to find some contracts that changed the perception of roman law in particular, and some well known contracts of that time, but I wasnt unable to do it, mainly because of the way this subject is teached and written in communist countries. Beside the hard facts, I am looking for any information that would make this theme a bit more interesting. 
Thank you in advance! 
Any links, works, or books that are free on the web would help me a lot, if you think this subject is too complex for this form

Answer (score 2):

https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=I_mLdBpi7eUC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=ancient+roman+law+contracts+responsibility+and+guilt&source=bl&ots=gz8A-IWnQP&sig=M7wOiZxbRKqRm5ZhMO5noDJ21tw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBWoVChMIpvHHjL-HyQIVgSyUCh0U3gO4#v=onepage&q=contract&f=false

I had a bit of a search but don't really know enough about the topic to help. Here is a link i found to a book that seems relevant.